# Bash script export/source strange behavior

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have 2 scripts:

1. script: **script1.sh**

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   [[ $0 = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && { echo "You must source me!"; exit; }
   if [ -z ${I} ]; then
        echo
        echo -n "some string: "
        stty -echo
        read I
        #export I
        stty echo
        echo
   else
        echo "ALREADY SET!!!"
   fi
   echo "--- $I"
   ```
2. script: **script2.sh**

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   echo "--- $I"
   if [ -z $I ]; then
           echo "VARIABLE NOT SET"
   else
           echo "VARIABLE SET"
   fi
   ```

And now the part that confused me... I first run script1 and then script2...

**First scenario:**

As you can see I can print $I variable (value: asd) inside script1. When I run script2 it returns "VARIABLE NOT SET", but when I try to echo $I I get "asd"

```
wolfy@VMtest:~$ . ./script1.sh

some string:
--- asd
wolfy@VMtest:~$ ./script2.sh
---
VARIABLE NOT SET
wolfy@VMtest:~$ echo $I
asd
wolfy@VMtest:~$
```

**Second scenario:**

Now I uncomment `#export I` and rerun both scripts as before (before rerun I created a new session so that all variables are reseted)

In this case I can read $I in script2 and echo it

```
wolfy@VMtest:~$ . ./script1.sh

some string:
--- asd
wolfy@VMtest:~$ ./script2.sh
--- asd
VARIABLE SET
wolfy@VMtest:~$ echo $I
asd
```

Can someone explain me why in my first scenario I can echo $I, but I can't use it in second script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't export it. Exporting a variable moves it from the current shell's variable list into the environment. Subprocesses only read existing variables from the environment.

Comment: thanks for your explanation... but why can I echo it from prompt?

Comment: Because the "prompt" *is* the current shell.

Comment: Absurdly minor nit.  It turns out 'export' does not necessarily move the variable into the environment.  In bash it does, but in general it merely ensures that the variable will be in the environment of all subprocesses.  Why any shell would choose to implement this behavior in any other way than simply putting the variable in the environment is baffling, but `dash` at least chooses not to do so.  (Or did at the last version I checked, which was a few years ago.)